# How to run page with specific url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have page access url : `http://*******.com/responsys-rest-api-optional-data.php` , which works fine no issue in that, what i want to do is, i want to run that page, with different url like `http://*******.com/tools/responsys-rest-api-optional-data`, can anyone please help me how to achieve that with `htaccess` ? i did something like but it is not working,

```
RedirectMatch "tools/responsys-rest-api-optional-data" "http://*******.com/responsys-rest-api-optional-data.php"
```

Comment: RedirectMatch is the wrong directive for this to begin with - you don’t want an external redirect, you want an internal rewrite. Go do a bit of research and find yourself one of the countless already existing “how to remove `.php` suffix from my URLs” questions.